# bootstrap-select, how to add data-style by jquery to selectpicker button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-select

Simply I would like to add and remove data-style, how to do?
I'm using bootstrap-select and class selectpicker for button.
I would like to change default btn-primary to btn-success, danger ect.

I'm really stuck, some css styles comes from bootstrap-select.
I'm not going to do custom stylin, just need to change button color.

**scripts.js**

```
$("#select_value").unbind("click");
   $("#select_value").click(function(){ 
});
```

**html**

```
<select id="select_value" class="selectpicker col-md-3"  data-dropup-auto="false" data-size="6"  name="select-value">
    <option value="1">Value 1/option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

bootstrap-select https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: Can you please share your code. And what you have tried.

Comment: add your own styles.css to index.html, include it AFTER bootstrap. target selector, style whatever you want. best would be to give you button an extra class name. br

Comment: I'm hoping to do this with jquery, add/remove data-style to select id in click events

Comment: btw, if I'm using class="btn btn-primary col-md-3", I can just use jquery .removeClass & .addClass. By some reason it doesn't work with selectpicker, probably css styles what came with bootstrap-select. Maybe best to get rid of whole damn boostrap-select?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436947/bootstrap-select-how-to-add-data-style-by-jquery-to-selectpicker-button